# sails.js ipv6 heroku?

Tags: heroku, socket.io, sails.js, ipv6

Short question: Does Sails.js function properly on Heroku with IPv6?

( Haven't really studied this deeply, but we seem to have some issues around socket.io and IPv6 in the US with specific android phones )

Answer (score 0):

sails.js should work just fine with Heroku and other hosting services on ipv6.

The answer sounds like it could be fairly specific to your unique situation; you'll want to post in Github or Gitter to get more specific support and recommendations from others in the community:

- https://gitter.im/balderdashy/sails
- https://github.com/balderdashy/sails